# Set domain on dashboard dyanmic

Tags: odoo

I want to generate dynamically dashboard on some condition given by wizard

I want to give start date and end date by wizard or by other option

Like for 01/01/2013 to 12/31/2013 these dates data used in dashboard,

how to give date value to dashboard?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have already answered this for yourself, I haven't yet found the dashboard to be dynamic so you will need a custom module to make this happen. For filters, you can try:

1) Start debug
2) Go to the list view you want to filter
3) Under debug menu, select Manage Filters
4) It will show My Filters by default, uncheck this to view all filters for this list view
5) When you click Create, it will allow you to enter your domain you wish to dynamically filter on

Example: `[('date_order', '=', (context_today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))]` in the domain will dynamically filter by the current day.

Like I said, even if you add this to the dashbaord, it won't update dynamically, but it will every time you select this filter in the list view.